# Mmult function difficulties

Tags: excel, wps

[image]

I am having troubles using the `mmult` function in excel. I selected the right arrays however it only fills in one cell. I want it to fill in all the cells. I have tried the Ctrl + Shift + Enter but still it does not work.

Comment: What is filled in the one cell?

Comment: Before committing the formula, you have to first select a range of cells with dimensions equal to those of the result of the operation. In your example, `MMULT` will produce an *18-row-by-31-column* array, so that is the dimension of the range you need to first pre-select in the worksheet before committing the formula.

Comment: @JosWoolley ok, sleepy today. But Excel will usually spill results to fill rows and columns where relevant (and often for me when i don't want tha), so is mmult() just different?

Comment: @SolarMike Only in O365, no spilling occurred in legacy versions of Excel, even for functions like `MMULT`.

Comment: So it is not possible for spill results without the legacy versions. Oh well, thanks anyway.

Comment: Just 186, wanted the rest to spill to the other cells